# Unexpected behavior when creating a custom append() method for lists

Tags: python, class

I am new to object oriented programming so I do not know much about creating a class, so this is confusing me. I have a class that I have made here:

```
class lst(list):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
    def appnd(self, *args):
        if len(args) > 1:
            print("you can only append one item")
            return
        else:
            if len(self) > 5:
                print("lst cannot be longer than 5 items")
            else:
                return self.append(args)
```

The purpose of this is to be able to create a variable with `a = 'lst()'` and have `a` behave as a list except include `appnd` as an additional method. I believe this has worked partially, but I get an unexpected output to the following code:

```
a = lst()
for i in range(7):
    a.appnd(i)
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[(0,)]
[(0,), (1,)]
[(0,), (1,), (2,)]
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,)]
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
lst cannot be longer than 5 items
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
lst cannot be longer than 5 items
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (3,), (4,)]
```

This is similar to what I want, but I expected:

```
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lst cannot be longer than 5 items
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
lst cannot be longer than 5 items
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Why is it showing tuples in the list? Can someone please explain the issue and how to solve it for this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how the `*args` syntax works.  You get a tuple, even if there is only one item.  The fact that you had to say `len(args)` should have been a clue.  So, just do

```
        return self.append(args[0])
```

And actually, the return is pointless.  `list.append` returns `None`.

Comment: Wow, seems too simple, I knew this, but for some reason assumed that the issue was coming from the fact that is was a class. Thank you for pointing this out!

Comment: Also thank you for explaining that I do not need to return self.append() I thought for the class to know it was appended I would have to return it (as you can tell this is my first time coding classes.)